# New membership page as default Drupal register page

Tags: drupal, civimember

Our non profit organisation has members who should have full access tot the web site.

We created in civicrm a contribution page with

1. no "contribution", only "membership" information
2. a choice between three types of membership
3. a civicrm profile with extra fields (address, phone number, birth day...)

Now, my question: how to get this page when the visitor goes to the Drupal register page? For the moment, only the civicrm profile is displayed, not the choice of the membership type.

Comment: So you are wanting to have a person choose a membership type and pay when they sign up for a Drupal account?  Therefore, just adding a membership field to your CiviCRM Profile will not suffice, correct?

Comment: @Allen, one is anonymous visitor or member. As a member he pays a contribution, has access to the members-only part of the web site, and receives a quarterly printed magazine. We do not have Drupal accounts who are not paid members.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware you can expose a profile on a Drupal user registration page, but not a contribution page. Assuming you will have at least some public-facing content that is not member-only, you can include within this some information about joining, with links to your contribution page.

As part of your profile settings, you can specify whether a user account is created. So, when a user submits the contribution form, they will provide a username and an email address, and a Drupal account will be created for them.

One thing to look out for - if your membership is paid, the Drupal account may well be created regardless of whether the payment is completed successfully or not.

Then you can use the CiviMember role sync module to give the new member a Drupal role with appropriate access permissions when they next log in.

Comment: Agree. And good point about needing to differentiate between Authenticated Drupal Users - which will include those who never get around to completing payments - and those who are fully-paid up members.

Comment: @Graham, but how to change the "new account" link in Drupal's "user login" block?

Comment: @petednz, Drupal user accounts who have not paid, stay "blocked" until payment. Once paid, the status is changed to "active".

Comment: Mark - hi - not sure if you are saying that is what you need, or that is what you have. If the latter, ie Drupal Users stay blocked until payment is made, are you doing this just via Rules or some other route? Is it something you have shared elsewhere as sounds useful for others

Comment: @petednz, nothing is operational today (on the production site), we are looking for the best solution today. Plan is that the membership manager checks the payment (which is done offline, as civicrm does not support the online payment in our country) and manually changes "blocked" into "active".

Comment: @MarkDQ What I've done on this issue with a drupal site before, primarily to stop spam user registrations, is set a redirect in the .htaccess file that simply takes anyone trying to get to /user/register to the front page. I've simply used CSS to hide links to the new account/register page that are otherwise visible on /user and /user/password (not too elegant, but it works) and so the only way in is via the Civi membership form.

Comment: @Graham, thx for reply.
We are using a shared hosting provider, who does not allow a rewrite rule in htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in Joomla in this situation is to first make a profile with the Joomla account creation option. Second make a plugin that redirects anyone who goes to the normal Joomla registration page to the profile page.  You could also do it without the plugin if you make a layout override for the login module that changes the link for the "create an account page"  go to your CiviCRM page and make a menu link to the Joomla account creation page that is special access. (Mainly I'm saying you want to avoid people directly typing in the create account URL.

Comment: where to find such a plugin? It seems that is one solution for my problem.

Comment: This idea would be like this https://gist.github.com/elinw/6735616d3e0e0cae823c ... but that's based on a 1.5 plugin so i added some comments indicating where you might want to change things.